# Multiple Maps on One Page - ColdFusion

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Getting stuck on Google Maps

Using ColdFusion - I am populating a list of Arena's...
I want a drop down of the maps if they have one - and link to add map.  Links to populate the map and mark it work fine.

When I have multiple entries - I don't get multiple maps - only get map showing of last result.

I've tried some other coding I have used in past - but still no luck with multiple maps - so starting with this easier looking javascript.

Any help is appreciated.   Deleting old code - going to what is currently working - just not showing markers

```
 <img src="../images/gps1.png" height=25 border=0 alt="Show Map" onclick="javascript:showElement('g#aid#')">
```

Also - when I use style="display:none;" with the Google Map Div:

```
  <div id="g#aid#" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;" style="display:none;"></div>
```

the drop down map is buggered and not centered.  Without it - it closes and opens just fine - but is always defaulting to open.

As suggested - Here is Javascript output...
Here is output below for 2 results... Only last one shows map..

Below is some progress - starting at Google API - This is where I'm at...

There is a body onload to make this work...

All maps are showing properly... even added another... Just not getting markers...
I have tried Google Marker code... No luck yet... So just going to code that is displaying maps properly...

Just need to figure map marker out...

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

    <cfoutput query=arena">


    <script>
    var map;
    function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(#arena.agpslat#,#arena.agpslong#),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('g#arena.aid#'),
        mapOptions);

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
   </script>

   <div id="g#arena.aid#" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;"></div>

    </cfoutput>
```

Adding this:  Does not get me a marker...

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: '#arena.arename#'
     });
```

Comment: You're still creating your `initialize` function more than once, implying it's still happening within your query loop.  Take a look at how I'm doing it in my answer.

Comment: I get no maps with below suggestion... Made sure to remove the initialize from body too... Still playing... With initial coding I can always get the 2nd map (just testing with 2 results) - which is always the last result.

Comment: The latest code you've added isn't displaying correctly - you need to [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15007155/edit), select the code, then press the code format button (the pair of braces **`{}`**) and it will format/escape that block of code appropriately.

Comment: Done peter... Sorry... Put code in working that is getting me the appropriate maps - just no markers now...

Comment: Heh, there's nothing to apologise for! I was simply making sure you knew code/tags needed that to display. (Unfortunately I don't know enough about Google Maps to offer any help with the actual question; I've only ever worked with Bing Maps.)

Comment: Actually, one thought (which may or not be the issue): you probably want `title: '#JsStringFormat(arena.arename)#'` - otherwise if the name contains an apostrophe it'll cause invalid JS.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're calling the JS file and defining an identically-named function within your query loop.  You need to move this stuff out of your query loop so you only call the file and create the function once.

So instead of having your initialise function recreated each time within the loop, move that out of the loop.  And instead have the call to that function from within the loop, passing the different lat/lng values, div ID's and names into it each time.

Get rid of any existing calls to your initialize functions from the body tag and just use the google event listeners for when the window loads, passing different parameters each time to `initialize`.

Something like the following:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

 <script>
  var arenas = []; // array of arenas, to be populated later within the query loop
  function initialize() {
    var intArena, myLatlng, mapOptions, map, marker;

    // loop over all the arenas, creating maps and markers for each
    for (intArena = 0; intArena < arenas.length; intArena++) {
      myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(arenas[intArena].lat, arenas[intArena].lng);
      mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(arenas[intArena].id), mapOptions);

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: arenas[intArena].name
      });
    }
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 </script>

<cfoutput query="arena">
  <cfif arena.agpslat is not "" and arena.agpslong is not "">
    <script>
      // add struct of arena data to the array for use later on in the initialize function
      arenas.push({
        lat: #arena.agpslat#, 
        lng: #arena.agpslong#, 
        id: 'g#arena.aid#', 
        name: '#JsStringFormat(arena.arenaname)#'
      });
    </script>

    <div id="g#arena.aid#" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;"></div>
  </cfif>  

  <div align=center>g#arena.aid#<br><b>[ <a href="arenagps.cfm?aid=#arena.aid#"><font color=cc3300>Change/Add Using Map Function</font></a> ]</b><br></div>
 </cfoutput>
```

Also please note I've prefixed the references to your query columns with the query name.  It's almost always a good idea to correctly scope all your variables.

Comment: No Go - All Blank... No Maps at all... Will keep playing... I scope variables when I need too... My understanding was to not do it when u don't need to - which keeps ur actual code needed a bit smaller/faster... Just quickly played with ur code Duncan... Will keep playing...

Comment: check for JS errors, and it may be useful to also add your generated JS to your question.  Scoping actually [improves performance](http://www.cfgears.com/index.cfm/2010/9/22/The-importance-of-proper-variable-scoping)

Comment: Duncan - ur code works too thx... I'll settle on one or the other... Now to get the infamous div style="display: none" to work. That one is a bit of a headache from what I understand too...

Answer (score -1):

Got... Thx for suggestions all...

Needs a

```
   <body onload="initialize()">
```

ColdFusion Coding - used the variable to rename the function and mapoption - so they are always different.

```
  <cfoutput query=arena>

  <cfif arena.agpslat is not "" and arena.agpslong is not "">

   <script type="text/javascript">
 function initialize() {
    var #arena.aid#Latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(#arena.agpslat#,#arena.agpslong#);

    var #arena.aid#Options = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: #arena.aid#Latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("g#arena.aid#"), #arena.aid#Options);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: #arena.aid#Latlng,
        map: map,
        title: '#arena.arenaname#'
      });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>

  <div id="g#arena.aid#" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;"></div>



  <div align=center>g#arena.aid#<br><b>[ <a href="arenagps.cfm?aid=#arena.aid#"><font color=cc3300>Change/Add Using Map Function</font></a> ]</b><br></div>

  </cfif>

 </cfoutput>
```

Comment: Sorry to downvote what appears to work for you, but this isn't a very good approach to take and I'm surprised it works at all (think about the code repetition you're making in the javascript)!  I'll edit my answer with a way to call the same initialize function with different parameters each time, from the body onload

Comment: In the end I don't pass any parameters to `initialize` - I create a global array of structures, each structure containing arena data.  Then the function simply loops over the array, adding markers and maps for each one